# Make Search Bar Become First Responder

Tags: swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` inside of a `UINavigationBar`. The user has to tap on a `UIBarButtonItem`, in which I instantiate a new `UIViewController` then present it, in order to begin searching.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var searchController: UISearchController! 

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSearchController()
  }

  func setupSearchController() {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
  }

}
```

I've done plenty of research before hand, but still can't manage to find a solution...

Help in making the search controller become the first responder would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Making the `UISearchBar` the first responder on the main thread was the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522062/when-assigning-focus-via-becomefirstresponder-to-uisearchcontrollers-uisearchba).

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
}
```

Comment: Superb.! With this solution its working regardless of the iOS version.

Comment: This works on iOS 13 as well. Fking Apple and their nonsense implementations.

Comment: It crashes in iOS 12 but in 13 is ok.